# How to make a user menu in ubuntu 22.04 so I can either continue to Ubuntu or start Clonezilla stand alone I looked for example but couldn't find it

Tags: grub2, 22.04, menu, clonezilla

I have Ubuntu desktop 22.04. I also use Clonezilla, but it is started from a USB stick.
Now I'd like to start Clonezilla from a partition on my hard disk with a custom menu. I'd like to have a menu at startup that is 1: continue to Ubuntu  and 2: start Clonezilla standalone
I tried, but it says it cannot find the user menu.

Comment: Have you tried to follow [Clonezilla's documentation](https://clonezilla.org/livehd.php)? If so, [please edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508956/edit) and add the exact step where it didn't work, and the exact error messages.

Comment: In most PC computers (desktops and laptops) there is a hotkey that you can use to get a temporary menu, where you can select which drive you want to boot from (typically the internal drive or a USB boot drive). Different computers have different hotkeys, but it is often F12. See the computer's manual or search the internet to find which key should be used in your computer. Sometimes it is enough to press the key right after booting (cold boot or reboot), sometimes you should tap it repeatedly (once every second) until the temporary menu appears.